# Javascript: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm having trouble with the for loop using 'j' as the counter. I'm not sure why the code stops there when I run it. Any help would be appreciated!

The goal is to accept a string of numbers and get the sum of each digit of every number and re-order the given strings of numbers according to their sums.

Here is my code:

```
function sortNumber(a,b) {
    return a - b;
}

function orderWeight(strng) {
  var theWeights = strng.split(' ');
  var weightsArr = weightSums(strng)
  var newArr = [];
  var sumArr = [];
  var obj = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < theWeights.length; i ++) {
    var weight = theWeights[i];
    var weightSum = weightsArr[i];

    sumArr.push([weight, weightSum]);
  }

  var arranged = weightsArr.sort(sortNumber);

  for (var j = 0; j < sumArr.length; j++) {
    var sum = sum[j];

      for (var k = 0; k < arranged.length; k++) {
        var sumArranged = arranged[k];

        if (sum.indexOf(sumArranged) > -1) {
          newArr.push(sum);
        }
      }

  }

  return newArr.join(' ');
}

function weightSums(strng) {
  var weightArr = [];
  var weights = strng.split(' ');

  for (var i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
    var weight = weights[i];
    var sum = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < weight.length; j++) {
      var num = Number(weight[j]);    
      sum += num;

    }
    weightArr.push(sum);
  }

  return weightArr;
}
```

Comment: in     `orderWeight var sum = sum[j];` isnt wrong?

Comment: yeah, that line is wrong - `sum` is first declared there, so it is still `undefined`.  The variable `j` is 0, thus the error "cannot read property '0' of undefined".

Comment: Also, you may be interested in looking up the `parseInt` function (and also its cousin `parseFloat`).  It looks like you may be parsing integers by hand in `weightSums` (and doing it wrong I might add - you need to multiply by 10 each iteration).

Comment: @jcarpenter2 For weightSums, my goal is to add all the digits of one number (in a given array of numbers) and push it into an array. For example, 1023 becomes 1 + 0 + 2 + 3 = 6. Is there a better way to do this? I'm just a beginner, hence the very long code.

Comment: Oh, that seems fine then.  I thought you were parsing base-10 numbers.